# Is there a way to identify what is Caching a particular file?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a  prolonged issue with the Cart file, on an ecommerce website I am working on.  The WordPress powered website, is using WooCommerce as the preferred shopping platform.  Simply, the Cart file is being Cached by the Browser and I cannot seem to prevent this.

I have tried many avenues but to no success.  Is there a way to identify what is caching the 'cart.php' file, in a bid to narrow down my focus on where the problem(s) could lie?  I have no Caching Plugins, my hosting provider has stated there are no server side caching resources, there are no issues with the theme and I have not modified the '.htaccess' file, to cache any files.

Hopefully, knowing what is causing the Caching, will help resolve the problem.

Comment: How do you know it's cached? May be you are editing the wrong file?

Comment: When a user adds an item to the Cart, they can then not remove the item, should they change their minds.  This has been identified as being because the Cart is being Cached.  I have tried many options, as detailed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408193/how-can-i-prevent-cart-from-being-cached-by-the-browser? Since I have not found any success yet, I was hoping there would be a way to identify what is causing the Cart to be cached as to hone in my efforts.

Comment: The cart data is not cached, It's just using `WC()->sessions`, `WC()->cart` `WC()->customer` objects (and cookies). You can see all this data through the `WC()` global object using : `echo '<pre>'; print_r( WC() ); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @LoicTheAztec Are you saying that the problem would not be Cache related?  As detailed in the above link, I have tried many avenues to remedy the problem but to no success.

Comment: How do you have the domain set-up, or are you using a temporary url from cPanel? This can actually effect stuff like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem.  I totally forgot I placed the following Caching Code into my `.htaccess` file.  As soon as the below code was removed, the problem was resolved.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check wp_config.php `define('WP_CACHE', false)` .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, this does not work neither.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with browser cache.. as you stated you have already asked your service provider and they dont have any cache in server and u didnt use any third party plugins either... Whenever u try to refresh use hard refresh( ctrl+shift+R ) for windows and ( cmd+shift+R ) for mac.. Sometimes browser cache can give lots of headache